# Link Not working ... Why?

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3

## Link is not working properly:

```
let MoovitURL: String = "moovit://nearby?lat=40.758896&lon=-73.985130&title=\(barNameTemplate)&partner_id=<nightout>"

        let escapedString = MoovitURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: escapedString!)!)
```

## Saying:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-08-14 22:49:35.983585+0300 TestApp[10658:6538686] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

## crashing on line:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: MoovitURL)!)
```

Comment: You have to percent escape your string

Comment: i already did, it makes the crash go away but the link is opened incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

Swift doesn't think your string is an actual URL, so it returned nil. When you tried to force unwrap it (`!`), it gave an error.

Comment: how can i make it think its a URL?

Comment: Don't answer duplicate questions.  Instead, vote to close them as duplicates.